# Is website.publishproj safe to modify?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I have a Website (not web application) project in VS 2015 which was imported from VS 2005.  When I went to go set up publish profiles for it, VS added a `website.publishproj` file to it.  I understand what this file is for, but it has a warning at the top of it:

> WARNING: DO NOT MODIFY this file, it is used for the web publish process.

Is it actually safe to modify this file?  Or does it get regenerated automatically, and thus any changes will be lost?

Comment: make a copy and try it..

Comment: @Legends - Well, yes.  But I don't want my changes to be blown away by something that someone else does in three weeks, even if they aren't right now.

Comment: Hm, the publishproj file is your web publish profile. So you can try to make manual changes, save it. And then make some changes to the profile using VS GUI, then you can see if it ovrrides it...